# Apache Velocity custom directive additional information

Tags: java, velocity

How can I obtain additional information after using a custom directive with apache velocity?

We have objects with a set of properties, each of which is a string which can be a velocity template. We have a custom directive so that the template can contain references to properties on other objects e.g:

```
public class Object
{
     public String name; //unique identifier

     public Map<String, String> properties ....

     public Object(String name)
     {
          this.name = name
     }
}

Object object1 = Object("object1")
object1.property("object1Key") = "object1Value"

Object object2 = Object("object2")
object2.property("object2Key") = "#ObjectProperty('object1', 'objectKey1')"
```

The 'processed' output of object2.property("object2Key") is "object1Value".

What I would like to do, is build a list which shows which properties reference a current property. For example:

```
Set<String> references = getReferences(object1, "object1Key")
```

and `references` would contain a set of strings which refer to the specified property. In this case, references would contain a string such as: "object2-object2Key", indicating that the `object1Key` property on `object1` is referenced by the `object2Key` property on `object2`.

I suspect that this can be accomplished by adding 'application attributes' to the 'VelocityEngine' object, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to take?